# WP_Query() and custom filter

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to display some posts on my wordpress blog using WP_Query(). 
The idea is to display 9 randomly selected posts among the posts which has been published in the last 30 days.
For some reasons, this doesn't seem to work.

Here is the code I use :

```
    function filter_where_custom( $where = '' ) {
        // posts in the last 30 days
        $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')) . "'";
        return $where;
    }

    $args = "orderby=rand&posts_per_page=9";
    $my_query = new WP_Query();
    add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where_custom');
    $my_query->query($args);
```

I think the problem lies with the use of add_filter but I've been unable to understand what I'm doing wrong so far.
Any help would be great :) 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should work, no need for a filter.
More on [time params](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Time_Parameters)

```
$args = array(
  'year' => date('Y', strtotime('-30 days')),
  'monthnum' => date('m', strtotime('-30 days')),
  'day' => date('d', strtotime('-30 days')),
  'orderby' => 'rand',
  'posts_per_page' => 9
);
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);

// start your custom $my_query->have_posts() loop
```